# Need help understanding double exports in this example for Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

There are 3 files: `src/Router.js`, `src/Components/Home/index.js` and `src/Componenets/Home/Home.js`.

`src/Router.js` has a single import from `Home`:

```
import Home from "components/Home";
```

Which reads from `src/Components/Home/index.js`:

```
export { default } from "./Home";
export * from "./Home";
```

Which subsequently reads from `src/Componenets/Home/Home.js`:

```
export class Home extends Component {
...
}

export default _flowRight(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  injectIntl
)(withCookies(Home));
```

How do these exports work? I'm a bit confused by the `{ default }` notation as it's a named value, yet default export? What exactly gets imported by `src/Router.js`? I'm usually familiar with the idea of default and named exports, but this way of exporting confuses me.

Comment: Your router will import the component return by connect

Comment: it will import `Home` class component when u import like this-> `import {Home} from "components/Home"`

Comment: So when it calls `import Home from "components/Home"`, does it import `__flowRight` or `Home`? I think it's `__flowRight` (which connects `Home`), but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: depends actually, what ur __flowRight is returning, I know about connect, it returns the same component with additional props